# How do you get Firefox in a portable format for Mac, Linux and Windows?

Tags: firefox

Is it possible to get Firefox in a portable format?

The only "portable" version of FireFox I can find is on portableapps.com and it is just an installer, and from what I hear you cannot package that in your own application.

How do you get a portable version of Firefox for Windows, Mac or Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For windows, just download the installer and run the Exe to completion then zip the result. This seems to work fine for use with Automated browser testing which is what I was using the portable zip for.

For Linux, you can just literally use the tar.bz2 file. It is basically portable in the default distribution already.

And for Mac you can mount the DMG file then just copy the zip contents.

One thing I also needed to do was to manually go through each file that started as executable and re-make them executable. Because the process of zipping up the files made the files non-executable.